# Is there any cons to defining functions (such as `add`) by listing all cases?

Tags: agda

Add is often defined as:

```
add : ℕ -> ℕ -> ℕ
add zero    m = m
add (suc n) m = suc (add n m)
```

This definition is short, but makes the proof of things like `add-comm` rather complex, requiring two inductive functions and calls to `subst`, `cong` and `sym`. If we, instead, define add as:

```
add : ℕ -> ℕ -> ℕ
add zero    zero     = zero
add (suc n) zero     = suc n
add zero    (suc m)  = suc m
add (suc n) (suc m)  = suc (suc (add n m))
```

Then the proof of commutativity becomes almost trivial:

```
add-comm : forall a b -> add a b ≡ add b a
add-comm zero    zero    = refl
add-comm zero    (suc b) = refl
add-comm (suc a) zero    = refl
add-comm (suc a) (suc b) = cong suc (cong suc (add-comm a b))
```

Is there any negative side to defining functions like `add` by listing all cases, rather than being economic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You win some definitional equalities, but you lose others. In this case, you lose that `add (suc a) b` is `suc (add a b)` for any `b`. In short, if you have more cases here, you need more cases and/or proofs elsewhere, for example for `Vec` appending:

```
open import Data.Vec

add-zero : ∀ n → add zero n ≡ n
add-zero zero    = refl
add-zero (suc n) = refl

suc-add : ∀ n m → suc (add n m) ≡ add (suc n) m
suc-add zero zero = refl
suc-add zero (suc m) = cong suc (cong suc (sym (add-zero m)))
suc-add (suc n) zero = refl
suc-add (suc n) (suc m) rewrite suc-add n m = refl

append : ∀ {n m}{A : Set} → Vec A n → Vec A m → Vec A (add n m)
append []       ys = subst (Vec _) (sym (add-zero _)) ys
append (x ∷ xs) ys = subst (Vec _) (suc-add _ _) (x ∷ append xs ys)
```

(the original `add-comm` doesn't require two definitions):

```
add : ℕ -> ℕ -> ℕ
add zero    m = m
add (suc n) m = suc (add n m)

add-comm : ∀ n m → add n m ≡ add m n
add-comm zero    zero    = refl
add-comm zero    (suc m) = cong suc (add-comm zero m)
add-comm (suc n) zero    = cong suc (add-comm n zero)
add-comm (suc n) (suc m)
  rewrite add-comm n (suc m)
        | sym (add-comm (suc n) m)
        | add-comm n m = refl
```

Comment: That definition of `append` is actually different from the standard one: it interleaves the elements of the two vectors instead of first taking all elements from the first one. If you want to write the standard `append` for this definition of `add`, you probably need to do some arithmetic in the types.

Comment: @Jesper how silly of me. I edited to implement the standard append.